# Splitting a conftest.py file into several smaller conftest-like parts

Tags: python, pytest

I've got a large conftest.py file that I wish to split into smaller parts, for two reasons:

1. The file is very large (~1000 lines, including documentation)
2. Some of the fixtures depend on other fixtures, and I have no reason to expose those other fixtures as part of the conftest "API" when users look for relevant fixtures

I am not aware of any mechanism provided by pytest to resolve conftest files in multiple locations within the same folder, so I contrived one, below:

```
import sys
import os


sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))


from _conftest_private_part_1 import *
from _conftest_private_part_2 import *
from _conftest_private_part_3 import *


@pytest.fixture
def a_fixture_that_is_part_of_the_public_conftest_api():
    pass
```

This works for my needs, but I do wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can put your stuff in other modules and reference them using a [pytest_plugins](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#using-fixtures-from-other-projects) variable in your `conftest.py`.

In the file `tests/unit/conftest.py`:

```
  pytest_plugins = [
     "tests.unit.fixtures.some_stuff",
  ]
```

In the file: `tests/unit/fixtures/some_stuff.py`:

```
  import pytest

  @pytest.fixture
  def foo():
      return 'foobar'
```

This will also work if your `conftest.py` has [hooks](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html?highlight=hooks#pytest-hook-reference) on them.

Comment: Can you show example code please?

Comment: As of 2022, Defining 'pytest_plugins' in a non-top-level conftest is no longer supported:
It affects the entire test suite instead of just below the conftest as expected.

Comment: @DPGraham4401 Would you be able to detail and/or link to the suggested solution?

Comment: Yes, [here under the deprecations and removal section for v 4.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/deprecations.html#:~:text=pytest_plugins%20in%20non%2Dtop%2Dlevel%20conftest%20files,-Removed%20in%20version&text=Defining%20pytest_plugins%20is%20now%20deprecated,tests%20at%20or%20below%20it.)

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't need any fancy magic for that. py.test automatically adds the path of the current test file to `sys.path`, as well as all parent paths up to the directory it was targeted at.

Because of that, you don't even need to put that shared code into a `conftest.py`. You can just put into plain modules or packages and then import it (if you want to share fixtures, those have to be in a `conftest.py`).

Also, there is this note about importing from `conftest.py` in the [documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins):

> If you have conftest.py files which do not reside in a python package
>   directory (i.e. one containing an `__init__.py`) then “`import conftest`”
>   can be ambiguous because there might be other `conftest.py` files as
>   well on your `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`. It is thus good practise for
>   projects to either put `conftest.py` under a package scope or to never
>   import anything from a `conftest.py` file.

Comment: I had wanted to be able to use the fixtures without them being in the "main" conftest.py file.  Glad to know about the path though.

Answer (score 4):

Alternativelly, you could try:

In `my_fixtures.py`:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def some_fixture():
  yield
```

In `conftest.py`:

```py
import my_fixtures


# Adding the fixture to attributes of `conftest` will register it
some_fixture = my_fixtures.some_fixture
```

It seems that `pytest` detect fixture by iterating over `conftest` attributes and checking for some `attr._pytestfixturefunction` added by `@pytest.fixture`.

So as long as `conftest.py` contains fixture attributes, it doesn't really matter which file is the fixture defined.

I haven't tried it but I would expect the following to work too:

```py
# In `conftest.py`
from my_fixtures import *
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and seems easier/clearer:

Top level tests/conftest.py (example of re-usable print debug of requests.Response):

```
import pytest
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.utils import dump


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def print_response(response: requests.Response):
    data = dump.dump_all(response)
    print("========================")
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    print("========================")

    print("response.url = {}".format(response.url))
    print("response.request = {}".format(response.request))
    print("response.status_code = {}".format(response.status_code))
    print("response.headers['content-type'] = {}".format(response.headers['content-type']))
    print("response.encoding = {}".format(response.encoding))
    try:
        print("response.json = {}".format(response.json()))
    except Exception:
        print("response.text = {}".format(response.text))
    print("response.end")
```

From lower level conftest import the higher level conftest code - e.g., tests/package1/conftest.py:

```
from tests.conftest import *
```

Then, in your lower level tests within tests/package1/test_*.py, you simply import via:

```
from tests.package1 import conftest
```

And then you have the merged configtests from one conftest available.  Repeat this pattern for your other lower level detailed/modular conftest.py files throughout the tests hierarchy.